# Which consoles support fee-less indie game publishing?

Tags: publishing

On which consoles can I publish indie games without paying a license fee?

Comment: "Best" is quite subjective. Even though right only a handful of options actually fit your criteria, I've removed "best" from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, all the major current and upcoming generation consoles (but one) don't make it possible to publish indie games without paying some kind of fee.

With the Xbox One, Microsoft's [ID@Xbox](http://www.xbox.com/en-us/Developers/id) program *may* provide what you are looking for. Currently, there's no explicit mention of payment on their site, but there's also no explicitly mention of gratis licensing, so you'll have to wait for more details to emerge as the console nears release, probably.

Additionally, right now they are only accepting applications from developers with a proven indie track record, so you may find getting accepted difficult.

Your next best bet is probably the [Xbox Live Indie Games](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/), on the 360 platform via XNA. This is not a free program -- membership costs $99 per year.

If you don't mind considering portable systems, Sony's mobile developer program also costs $99 per year, but as of May 8th [Sony had stated that the fee for indie developers would be waived](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2013/05/sony-waives-99-mobile-development-fee-in-play-for-indies/).

Comment: Isn't OUYA publishing free too?

Comment: I have no idea. If you can find a citation supporting it, feel free to edit it into my answer.